# How to print a double quote string in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a requirement to display double quote string in vf page.
This is the scenario.

I am storing a string with double quotes like

> "Test01"

In apex I am fetching value like this

```
selectedSearchName = String.escapeSingleQuotes( userColumnPrefs[0].SmartDashGrid_Saved_Search__r.Search_Name__c); //Tried with including this line as well instead of below one


selectedSearchName = userColumnPrefs[0].SmartDashGrid_Saved_Search__r.Search_Name__c;
```

I am getting the value in apex as "Test01"

When I try to retrieve in VF page the variable is getting empty

This is how I am retreiving

```
 var selectedSearch = "{!selectedSearchName}"; //Empty in console.
 var selectedSearch = '{!selectedSearchName}'; //Empty in console
```

I tried all possible ways.Please help me.

> **Here is how it works**

The apex is called when I select a value from picklist. With  the help of action function the apex method is called. I am  using selectedSearchName declared in apex to store the selected value from apex. If I select "test01"(in picklist it show like this not test01) from picklist I am getting empty value in VF page. I tried by replacing double quotes in "test01" with under-score, that time I am getting the value as expected. Now I believe the problem is with double quotes

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the parameters:

```
var selectedSearch = "{!JSENCODE(selectedSearchName)}"; //Empty in console.
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Still I am getting it as empty. It is getting like "test123" in debug logs. If I try without double quotes it is working perfectly. How can I solve this

Comment: Without more context, I can't help you further. I'd need to know when this Apex is being called, when the script is rendered, etc. If it's empty, it's because you've rendered it at the wrong time.

Comment: Is there any specific format to store double quote string in apex

Comment: @SFKID Nope. Using JSENCODE in VF is the piece that needs to happen.

Comment: okay. Thanks for reaching out